# How to redirect Ngrok to my website?

Tags: web, ngrok

I am trying to show my local-website to the customer but it doesn't works.
The provided link redirect him to the Xampp page, not to the website folder I want to.

Couldn't find any solution online to it.

Should I put the ngrok.exe in the website-folder or what?

port is 80, 443 (as shown on xampp)

Answer (score 1):

Use the -host-header option to direct to whichever virtual host on XAMPP you want to target.

`ngrok http -host-header=example.dev 80`